# How do I assign a delegate to multiple classes

Tags: iphone, delegates, delegation

I have a custom delegate, and I want 2 classes to respond to it's events.  How can I assign it to both classes.

ie:

```
viewController.delegate = firstClass && self;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need an event to be called multiple places you should use NSNotificationCenter.

Comment: Yea, I thought about that, but my delegate methods have like 3 arguments.  So in order to use `NSNotificationCenter`, I would have to bundle all them in an array.  And I just though it made more sense to use a delegate rather ran a notification

Comment: Plus, I didn't know you could send a noification to multiple instances. I've only ever sent a notification to one place

Comment: I ended up using a mix a both a delegate and a notification.  The code got really complex so it's probably not the best route, but it works, so I'm just gunna stick with it

Comment: To send to multiple do this post notification is only written at one place but you can add more than one observers as much as you want also don't forget to remove observers either in dealloc or in viewWillDisappear method.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a third class that handles the event by delegating it to the two classes.

```
viewController.delegate = delegatingClass;
```

...and in the object referred to as `delegatingClass`, implement the method that you're concerned about by calling that same method on the two classes you want to handle the event. For example:

```
void handleEvent( Event event ) {
    firstClass.handleEvent( event );
    otherClass.handleEvent( event );
}
```